# Show a Text after selected values from pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

[image: Screesnshot]

I want to get a text in the viewController after the user selected values from both pickerViews.

A calculate is not needed.

Let's say for example: I click on the first picker on "25 Jahre" and in the 2nd I select "50 Euro". Now I need the text under the TextFields.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController3Rechner: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var LaufZeitText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var BeitragText: UITextField!

    var Laufzeit = ["10 Jahre", "15 Jahre", "20 Jahre", "25 Jahre", "30 Jahre", "35 Jahre", "40 Jahre"]
    var Beitrag = ["50 Euro", "75 Euro", "100 Euro", "125 Euro", "150 Euro", "175 Euro", "200 Euro", "250 Euro", "300 Euro"]

    let picker  = UIPickerView()
    let beitrag = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        beitrag.delegate = self
        beitrag.dataSource = self

        // binding textfield to picker
        LaufZeitText.inputView = picker
        BeitragText.inputView = beitrag
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var countrows : Int = Laufzeit.count
        if pickerView == beitrag {
            countrows = self.Beitrag.count
        }

        return countrows
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == picker {
            let titleRow = Laufzeit[row]
            return titleRow
        } else if pickerView == beitrag {
            let titleRow = Beitrag[row]
            return titleRow
        }

        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == picker {
            self.LaufZeitText.text = self.Laufzeit[row]

            self.view.endEditing(true)

        } else if pickerView == beitrag {
            self.BeitragText.text = self.Beitrag[row]

            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your code look like so far?

Comment: oh sorry: edited

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should already allow each textfield to individually  populate when a row is selected in your picker views.

From what I can understand in your question, you want BOTH to fill ONLY WHEN BOTH pickers have had a row selected.

Create two new `String` variables,  `laufZeit` and `beitrag`

```
var laufZeit: String?
var beitrag: String?
```

Set these strings in your `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow` function, replacing the setting on the textFields text property.

```
if pickerView == picker {
    laufZeit = self.Laufzeit[row]

    self.view.endEditing(true)

} else if pickerView == beitrag {
    beitrag = self.Beitrag[row]

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

There are two ways you can do this next step, either within the `didSet` of each of the new `String` variables, or just below the above if/else statements.

Either way you'll want it to look something like this:

```
if let laufZeitString = laufZeit, let beitragString = beitrag {
    self.LaufZeitText.text = laufZeitString
    self.BeitragText.text = beitragString
}
```

So if both variables are set, then both textfields will get populated. I'd throw this into its own function, maybe `populateTextFields()`.